# Is "there neither existed a ..." a idiomatic phrase?

Tags: conjunctions, negation, existentials

The phrase only gives [14 results](https://www.google.com.tw/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22There%20neither%20existed%20a%22&tbm=bks) on Google. So, it makes me wonder if it is idiomatic or not.

Example sentence:

> There isn't an appropriate place to break up. **There neither exists** a spot to stand after the ordeal.

**EDIT:**

Maybe this sounds more idiomatic?

> There isn't an appropriate place to break up. **Neither one** to stay at*
>   after the ordeal.

_* not sure if *at* is the correct preposition

(I think I'm convinced now that **there neither existed** is not idiomatic.)

Comment: Idiomatic? Is such a sentence commonly used by native English speakers? No. But it would easily be understood by most readers or listeners (providing it is preceded, as this is, by a sentence with a corresponding negative like _is**n't**_) and although it violates some prescriptivist decrees, it is not an impossible usage in English.

Comment: You may want to consider: "There isn't an appropriate place to break up.  Neither does there exist a [safe] spot to stand after the ordeal."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There neither exists a spot to stand after the ordeal.

I can't think of a sentence or situation where this works as written.  The usual structure is "neither [A] nor [B]" and, while it's permissible to have the *nor* without the *neither*, *neither* must be paired in some way with a *nor* or a *not*. While there is a "not" in the first sentence, it's not really *paired* with the neither in the second, since they're talking about two different things.

Here's how you could write it:

> There isn't an appropriate place to break up. There doesn't exist a spot to stand after the ordeal.

This sentence doesn't make any sense to me, because I don't understand how "breaking up" has to do with where you will stand afterwards, but it is grammatical.

Here's an example of one that does work (although it's very informal English):

> There isn't an appropriate place to sit around here.  Neither can you stand.

In this case "sit" and "stand" are related actions, so the comparison makes sense.  You can also say this, which is more "proper":

> There isn't an appropriate place to sit around here, nor can you stand.

Edit:  As a side note, if I understand your intention correctly, you can write the sentence as:

> There's never a "good" place to break up with someone -- but if you can, pick a place where you can make a easy getaway.

Comment: The sentence means, figuratively, that it's never feels okay to break up.

Comment: @alex right, I get that.  If I understand your intention, please see my edit to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

*Neither* should be paired with *nor*:

> There existed **neither** a spot to stand on **nor** a place to sit after the ordeal.

If you don't want to include an alternative, then you should use *not*:

> There existed **not** a spot to stand on after the ordeal.

Comment: Technically aye, a prescriptivist would say, but nought requires that every neither have its nor in common speech. In the cited text, _Neither_ clearly has its negative apposite in _isn't_ in the preceding sentence. The meaning is clear (if the word order of the second sentence reads like a Google translation from the Slavo-Serbian.)

Comment: Oh, dear! I'm too tired to edit it right now.

Comment: You're right for Bo Peep and Uncle Ned then.

Comment: It's time to wind the cat up and put the clock out.